# Installed Google Earth won't launch

Tags: google-earth

Ubuntu 11.10 Gnome-shell 64bit
After installation Google Earth doesn't start

Comment: Have you installed the 64-bit version of Google Earth?

Comment: Can you try to launch the application from the terminal, and let us know the output?

Comment: I also installed Google Earth on my 11.10 64bit. It displays banner page and quits. The log file says: Major Version 6
Minor Version 0
Build Number 0003
Build Date May 17 2011
Build Time 00:40:40
OS Type 3
OS Major Version 3
OS Minor Version 0
OS Build Version 0
OS Patch Version 0
Crash Signal 11
Crash Time 1325626483
Up Time 1.00101 Stacktrace from glibc:
/usr/lib/googleearth/libgoogleearth_free.so(+0xab953)[0xf76b8953]
/usr/lib/googleearth/libgoogleearth_free.so(+0xabad3)[0xf76b8ad3]
[0xf7735400]

Answer (score 6):

My system is Ubuntu 11.10 and I was using Google earth without any problems until this morning. Last night I was using Google earth and this morning it would not start. I looked all over for a solution and came across this thread: [Installed Google Earth won't launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90553/installed-google-earth-wont-launch)  Then I tried to start it from the terminal as suggested and this is the output. As you can see, it shows that Google earth was already running and asks you to delete the file instance-running-lock. I deleted it and voila, it now runs again.

```
$ googleearth
Google Earth appears to be running already. Please kill the
 existing process, or delete /home/outlawradioinc/.googleearth/instance-running-lock if this is an error.
$ googleearth
```

I hope this helps some of the people out there that are having similar problems.